# Monotouch: Create image reflection?

Tags: uikit, xamarin.ios

I would like to make a reflection to an image - like this:

[image]

Is that possible in Monotouch?

Thanks!

Mojo

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, considering that you have full access to CoreGraphics.

There are too many ways of skinning that cat though.

Say you have the top image in "image", I would do something like:

1. Create a graphics context
2. Draw the image
3. Create a bitmap context for the inverted image, with alpha transparency
4. Render the image invertd
5. Render a gradient that has been configured to go from 0.5 opaque to 0.2 opaque
6. Render that on the bottom of the image
7. Get an image out of the second context
8. Draw the extracted image into the first context, inverted.